# What kind of maze Solving Algorithm is this?

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

I am trying to figure out if this algorithm is A* (A-Star) Algorithm or whatever but still I am confused.

```
Stack<Cell> stack = new Stack<>();

stack.push(maze.start());
stack.peek().mark(SOLUTION_MARK);

while (!stack.peek().hasMark(Cell.END)) {

    Cell current = stack.peek();
    ArrayList<Cell> dirs = current.neighbors();

    boolean found = false;
    for (Cell next : dirs) {
        if (next.hasMark(ERROR_MARK) || next.hasMark(SOLUTION_MARK)) {
            continue;
        }
        stack.push(next);
        next.mark(SOLUTION_MARK);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    if (!found) {
        stack.pop().mark(ERROR_MARK);
    }
    for (MazeBody listener : listeners) {
        listener.repaint();
    }
}
```

**Mark.java**

```
public final class Mark {

    private static Map<String, Mark> TABLE = new HashMap<>();

    private String name;

    private Mark(String markName) {
        name = markName;
    }

    public static Mark get(String name) {
        Mark mark = TABLE.get(name);
        if (mark == null) {
            mark = new Mark(name);
            TABLE.put(name, mark);
        }
        return mark;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, add the relevant language tag (I know it's Java, but I shouldn't have to guess).

Comment: Can you provide the definition for mark? This looks to me as a simple depth-first search but with global marking of visited.

Comment: @LucasMoeskops: no, it marks the places already visited. So it will run in at most O(n^2) with n the number of cells.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added Mark.java code

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I realised after posting so I deleted the comment :-) What I meant was, that there was no optimisation besides just walking all nodes, like a* star does (moving in the `cheapest` direction).

Answer (score 6):

This is **Depth First Search written iteratively** rather than recursively.

Recursive DFS (preorder) pseudocode looks like:

```
visit (current node)
for each child node of current node
    if node is not explored
        dfs (node)
```

Iterative version of DFS looks like:

```
Put current node on stack
In a while loop pop the stack if not empty
    visit (popped node)
    push all Unvisited and NotVisiting neighbors of popped node on the stack
End while
```

*Unvisited and NotVisiting* in the Iterative version means that the node is neither visited before, nor it is in the stack for visiting.

---

The **time complexity** of this algorithm depends on whether the graph has been stored as adjacency list or adjacency matrix. For list, it'd be O(n). For matrix, it'd become O(n<sup>2</sup>) because even though you explore every node only once, you have to visit every row and column of the matrix to know if there is a path between a node X and node Y.

The **space complexity** of this algorithm can go to worst of O(n), happening when the graph would have each node having only one neighbor, becoming like a singly linked list.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that it does an occurrence check: check whether the node has already been added to the stack.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you show I would say it is **depth-first search, but with a check** whether the place has already been scheduled for visit. Since it uses a stack, it will always first visit the places deeper in the search tree. But from the moment it adds a place to the stack, it marks the place as a solution mark to prevent it from being *re-evaluated* if another path would reach the same place.

Note however that it will mark every tile a `SOLUTION_MARK` unless it cannot come up with nodes others than marked with a `SOLUTION_MARK` or an `ERROR_MARK`. It will thus mark more tiles than the tiles contributing to (shortest) the solution. In that sense it is not really a maze solving algorithm: it simply marks tiles as `SOLUTION_MARK` if there is at least another tile not yet scheduled that *can* contribute to a solution. The algorithm will finish if it has marked all *reachable* tiles.

Comment: So the complexity is `O(n^2)`, where `n` is the total number of `cells visited` regardless Marked as `Error` or `Solution`, right ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanWahdan: if every neighbour can have *n* cells yes. Say you can move only in for instance `4` directions, the time complexity is O(n).